# How to download image stored in SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql, guid

I am creating a web form application that allows a user to upload image file to a folder and store its path in a database. I want to use a link button that will download the file from the database

This is my code for uploading

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Orders SET PaymentImage = @Image, PaymentStatus = @PaymentStatus WHERE OrderNo = @OrderNo AND PaymentStatus = 'Pending'; ";

    string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(fuImage.FileName);
    string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", id + fileExt);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PaymentStatus", "Payment Sent");

    fuImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/img/payments/" + id + fileExt));

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

UPDATE 2 : This is what i've tried for the download button

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String orderNo = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT OrderNo, PaymentImage FROM Orders WHERE OrderNo=@OrderNo";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Guid id = (Guid)(dr["PaymentImage"]);          
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/img/payments/" + id + ".jpg"));
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Now im getting this error "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: You only store the link in the database, not the whole image. What part is troubling you, what did you try? It seems like a very basic thing to me.

Comment: pretty sure there will be a duplicate somewhere here: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=download+image+from+database+C%23&oq=download+image+from+database+C%23&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.7073j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 However, it seems like your question title might be wrong because looking at that upload code you're saving the image to disk, and just saving its filename to the database. So you just need to retrieve the filename from the DB and generate a hyperlink to that.

Comment: @PeterBons i dont know how to retrieve the link that is stored in PaymentImage. Ive already updated my post

Comment: @ADyson oh my bad, but yeah youre correct. Can you check what i tried? I tried to retreive but it wont work

Comment: the problem is that compiler does not understand that @PaymentImage is variable and thinks that it is just a string. I'm not familiar with SQLCommand class, but try to save PaymentImage column from your query result to some kind of placeholder and than concat it to your uri. And yeah, I think you shuold execute query before adding data to server response

Comment: You will need to read the results of the command to actually get the data from the database. `ExecuteNonQuery` is for updates, inserts and deletes. To get result you will need `ExecuteReader`, see http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-sqlcommand-executereader.htm for an example.

Comment: As @PeterBons says, you are building a query, but executing a non-query. Also, you should _first_ execute the query before trying to do anything with the results. Why do you expect to have anything called a "@Paymentimage" before you even execute your query?

Comment: I did what you told me, now i only need to get the guid from the database but im getting "specified cast is not valid"

Comment: You are mixing up Id and PaymentImage which is very confusing. You are storing the Id as a string, you want to use it as a string, why do you do `Guid id = (Guid)(dr["PaymentImage"]); ` if you add the extension yourself later on again? Why not use `string id = dr["OrderNo"])`? Actually, that is the same OrderNo that you receive as a parameter! Why even perform the query at all? What is wrong with `String orderNo = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString(); Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/img/payments/" + orderNo + ".jpg"));` ?

Comment: Sorry, you are indeed working with different Id's. Please clean up your variable names, they lead to a lot of confusion. use `string id = dr["PaymentImage"])` and use that. Also, remove the .jpg if you already added an extension to your PaymentImage when inserting.

Comment: In upload code, you are saving id + extension in "PaymentImage" column but in download code, you used this column as "id" and added ".jpg" extension name in code!

Comment: @oerkelens Yeah youre right. I was mixing up guid and id, i tried to use string id = dr["PaymentImage"]) and its working now. Thanks for the help!